# Requests library and logging into websites with CSRF_TOKEN

Tags: python, post, get, python-requests, csrf

I've been trying to automate logging into a website and pulling statistics with no success. There are 3 key things to logging in, two of which I've been able to solve (getting the session id and sending the proper cookies), while the other I have not. Once logged in, the website generates a CSRF_TOKEN, which is then passed in the headers to all other POST and GET calls. While using Fiddler, I was able to capture the following events once the login button is pressed:

```
POST https://admin.------.com/login.html HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.------.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 115
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: https://admin.------.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: https://admin.------.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ecc=GBTnR4965BGJJeXzH5CM9Abg; ece=GBTnR4965BGJJeXzH5CM9Abg; ecid=GBTnR4965BGJJeXzH5CM9Abg

ses=4c17c8999aa61c3472710273fe0ea864&loginname=------&password=------&lang=xu&login=Login+&csrf_token=empty-token
```

The 'ses' is a session id that is generated in the page's HTML on pageload, which I was able to extract while running the page content thorugh BeautifulSoup and submitting it with the above POST. Immediately after, before I do anything else, the following comes up in Fiddler as well:

```
GET https://admin.------.com/index-home.html?page=&lang=xu&ses=4c17c8999aa61c3472710273fe0ea864&t=1417571941 HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.------.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://admin.------.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ecc=GBTnR4965BGJJeXzH5CM9Abg; ece=GBTnR4965BGJJeXzH5CM9Abg; ecid=GBTnR4965BGJJeXzH5CM9Abg; cwd-extranet=1; slan=xu
```

While looking at the Raw response from this GET, the following script is in the `<head>` of the page:

```
<script>
    (function( win, doc ) {
        var token                = 'paZ+VAAAAAA=e9oFyrkVK_0x9W7O76Y5cXt5vBKStXJA75VNRmhRCnRAQdX_o_zTomF4khrR6W2CamA86UbHSq8NizmpMT2Rfgd6DXHbMaIwr3G-chjiwmFCpnMiIGb4ECkGpSr846WRfAPy_0Cmcm6iqxREC5JpdklwAw849530pTe-Nw' || 'empty-token',
            eventCompliant       = typeof win.addEventListener === 'function',
            builder              = win.XMLHttpRequest || new win.ActiveXObject( 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' ),
            isBuilderConstructor = builder.prototype && builder.prototype.send,
            send                 = isBuilderConstructor ? builder.prototype.send : builder.send;

        if ( isBuilderConstructor ) {
            builder.prototype.send = sendWrapper;
        } else {
            builder.send = sendWrapper;
        }
        if ( eventCompliant ) {
            doc.addEventListener( 'submit', injectToken );
        } else if ( doc.attachEvent ) {
            doc.attachEvent( 'onmouseup', injectToken );
            doc.attachEvent( 'onkeydown', injectToken );
        }
        function sanitizeEvent( evt ) {
            return evt || win.event;
        }
        function eventType( evt ) {
            var e = sanitizeEvent( evt );
            return ( evt.type || '' ).toLowerCase();
        }
        function eventTarget( evt ) {
            var e = sanitizeEvent( evt );
            return e.target || e.srcElement;
        }
        function eventKeyCode( evt ) {
            var e = sanitizeEvent( evt );
            return e.keyCode || e.which;
        }
        function isEnterPressed( evt ) {
            return eventKeyCode( evt ) === 13;
        }
        function isSubmitButton( target ) {
            var isElement       = target && target.nodeName,
                isInputOrButton = isElement && /input|button/.test( target.nodeName.toLowerCase() );
            return isInputOrButton && target.type === 'submit';
        }

        function isForm( target ) {
            var isElement = target && target.nodeName;
            return isElement && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'form';
        }
        function appendToken( form ) {
            var input;
            if (
                form &&
                form.method &&
                form.method.toLowerCase() === 'post' &&
                typeof form.elements.csrf_token === 'undefined'
            ) {
                input       =  doc.createElement( 'input' );
                input.name  = 'csrf_token';
                input.type  = 'hidden';
                input.value =  token;
                form.appendChild( input );
            }
        }
        function closestForm( target ) {
            var elem = target;
            while ( elem && ! isForm( elem ) ) {
                elem = elem.parentNode;
            }
            return elem;
        }
        function injectToken( evt ) {
            var type   = eventType( evt ),
                target = eventTarget( evt ),
                actions = {
                    submit: function() {
                        appendToken( target );
                    },
                    mouseup: function() {
                        if ( isSubmitButton( target ) ) {
                            appendToken( closestForm( target ) );
                        }
                    },
                    keydown: function() {
                        if ( isEnterPressed( evt ) ) {
                            appendToken( closestForm( target ) );
                        }
                    }
                };
            ( actions[ type ] || Function() )();
            return true;
        }
        function sendWrapper() {
            this.setRequestHeader( 'X-Booking-CSRF', token );
            send.apply( this, [].slice.apply( arguments ) );
        }
    })( this, this.document );
</script>
```

That third line that establishes `var token` is the CSRF_TOKEN I need. The problem is, while running all of this through Python's Requests library, that CSRF_TOKEN doesn't generate, and instead, when i return the content of the page, the 3rd line of code is:

```
var token                = '' || 'empty-token',
```

Is there something I'm missing, or can anyone give any insight on how to accomplish this?

Comment: The token is added dynamically during page load. Usually it is not exposed to the end user/client, and if it is exposed(by mistake or something) it is considered a vulnerability.

Comment: @TarunGaba Hmm. So it loads in a browser's source code, but not while using the Requests library. I know I can automate the process (becacuse i already have) by using Selenium, but I'd like to be able to get rid of Selenium for multiple reasons. From what you know, is there any way possible of capturing that token at all? I'm using `requests.Session()` to have persistent cookies across the requests, but this is just the one part that is not working.

Comment: As far as I know, the token is present in the cookie also. You need to capture the cookies, and somehow parse them. But my part of knowledge is upto here only .. :)